# Maximal number of leaders in the tournament.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let's call a leader in the tournament such participant $L$, that won with every other participant directly or indirectly. Show that a leader always exists. Find the maximal number of leaders in the tournament with $n$ participant.

So far, I was able to prove that a leader in the tournament always exists (considering spanning road (such road that visit every vertex once).

But I have no idea how to prove the second part: maximal number of leaders.
Any HINTS how to start with the second part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: What if the tournament includes a large directed cycle?

Comment: Ok, in such case it will be $n$. But I thought that we have any tournament with $n$ vertices and for such a graph we should find maximal number?

Comment: @JosephConrad: I interpret the question to mean that you’re to find the maximum possible number of leaders in a tournament on $n$ vertices. It is of course possible to have as few as one, if the tournament is transitive, and $n$ is clearly the maximum possible.

Comment: Isn't any number between $1$ and $n$ possible? If $1 \leq k \leq n$ pick a tournament $T_1$ on $k$ vertices with a directed cycle, another tournament $T_2$ on $n-k$ vertices with a directed cycle and put all the arrows between them from $T_2$ to $T_1$.

Comment: @N.S.: Sure, but it’s the $n$-cycle that answers the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes I know. My comment was addressed more to JC's extra question, namely that for a particular tournament any answer is possible...